# can an android service or activity know which intent opened it?

Tags: java, android, service

In my androidManifest my mainActivity have few system intent filter.

is there any way to detect which intent filter opened my activity?

same goes to android service - is there a way to detect?

I know a `broadcast` has a ctor with intent and there I can analyze which intent woke it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an **activity** you can use getIntent() method to retrieve the intent used to start that activity.

> public Intent  getIntent()
>
> Return the intent that started this activity.

In your **service** you can check the intent you receive via parameter in the onStartCommand(..) method:

```
public int  onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

Then in both cases, with your "caller" Intent, you can compare its values, for example the action, to check which filter was used:

```
intent.getAction().equals(YOUR_FILTER_ACTION);
```

Or if you have another intent to compare with, you can use the filterEquals() method:

```
intent.filterEquals(anotherIntent);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method getIntent() on the onCreate() of an Activity to get the intent that started the activity or service, and then get the action and extras from the intent.

However, you can't know who called your activity or service, this is not possible to know in android.